# How can I prevent elements from touching/colliding in jointjs?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am using jointjs to create an interactive flowcharting application, is there a way to prevent elements from being dragged over the top of one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can revert the position of an element when the user finishes dragging and overlap is found.

```js
paper.on({
    'element:pointerdown': (elementView, evt) => {
        // store the position before the user starts dragging
        evt.data = { startPosition: elementView.model.position() };
    },
    'element:pointerup': (elementView, evt) => {
        const { model: element } = elementView;
        const { model: graph } = paper;
        const elementsUnder = graph.findModelsInArea(element.getBBox()).filter(el => el !== element);
        if (elementsUnder.length > 0) {
            // an overlap found, revert the position
            const { x, y } = evt.data.startPosition;
            element.position(x, y);
        }
    }
});
```